# Design rule for reusing API models for DB models

Tags: database, rest, web-applications, model, entities

We have a REST backend which works with model classes in order to encapsulate data for API calls. At this moment we are using the same model classes to map data into the DB.

As it saves copying the data from the API-domain into the DB-domain, there are some problems with this approach:

- It introduces security risks because you need to explicitly mask-off fields that are not allowed to be set in the DB directly from the API which is easy to forget.
- API model classes are "poluted" with DB-domain specific members that are not supposed to be served over the API.
- It becomes harder to refactor the DB layer without changing (accidentally) the API models.

On the other side, when copying there is:

- A problem with returning (big) lists.
- An easy caveat to forget copying (new) properties from the API domain to the DB domain and vice versa.

I wonder if there is a design rule which says something about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do is to separate your business entities (the model that you write into the database) from your data transfer objects (i.e. use the DTO pattern). So what you have in the end is :

1. DTOs which are only containers for your that is data coming from the rest
2. Business logic that reads the incoming data, makes some manipulations over it and transforms it into entities, that are going to be written/read in the database via DAOs or in some other way.
3. Model entities which represent your database model.

In this way at least you achieve separation of concerns (security, api change, data transfer).

Now this as everything in life (Except beer :) ) has its negatives:
For instance you get duplicated code (you have to duplicate the model from your db entities in the dto), which might make some overhead.

Hope that helps. 
Don't know what language you use, but here's an example in java : 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/transferobject-139757.html

Comment: OK, this means for our backend we have 2 sets of DTO's: one for API domain, and one for DB. I prefer separation (less error-prone) above (a tiny) optimization so that makes sense, thanks!